# TextView de activity null cuando quiero setear texto de respuesta de retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, nullpointerexception, textview

Estoy intentando hacer una app para consultar el clima usando OpenWeatherMap, Kotlin, Retrofit y MVP con arquitectura limpia.

La app es muy simple, tiene una sola activity y el layout muestra diferentes datos según la localidad que el usuario seleccione. 
Al iniciar la activity, esta inicializa el presenter en el oncreate y llama al método que inicia el proceso de request.
Al volver a mi activity con la respuesta, estoy tratando de mostrar cierta información de esa respuesta en un TextView, pero la app crashea porque esa vista es nula.
Estoy usando Kotlin Android Extensions, lo cual me permite, teóricamente, invocar la view solo con su id, sin necesidad de usar findViewById.
Soy nuevo en Kotlin y quizás se me esté pasando algo por alto.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MainActivityView {

var presenter: MainActivityPresenter? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    presenter = MainActivityPresenterImpl()
    presenter!!.getMainWeather("London")
}

override fun showCurrentCity() {
    presenter!!.getCurrentCity()
}

override fun showMainWeather(mainWeather: MainWeather) {
        mainTemperature.text = mainWeather.main!!.temp.toString() // AQUÍ INTENTO SETEAR EL TEXTO. PERO "mainTemperature"  ES NULL
}

override fun showFiveDaysWeather(cityName: String) {
    presenter!!.getFiveDaysWheather(cityName)
}

override fun showError(error: String) {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}
```

}

Comment: Estas seguro que mainTemperature es null? Por lo que veo creería que es mainWeather.main, recuerda que el uso del operador !! producirá NPE  cuando la variable invocada sea nula. Intenta usar safe calls (?) en lo posible, recuerda que una de las ventajas de kotlin es la seguridad de nulos y al usar operadores !! pierdes esa ventaja.

Comment: Resulta que si uso el debugger, veo que mainWeather.main trae los datos. Pero si quiero poner toda esa línea en un Toast por ejemplo, también se produce el NPE. :(

Answer (score 0):

Usando Kotlin puedes obtener la referencia de la vista,en este caso el TextView sin usar:

```
  findViewById<TextView>(R.id.<id textView>)
```

Que es lo que se acuerdo a tu código se esta realizando; por lo tanto, dentro del archivo `activity_main.xml` debes tener un `TextView` definido y su id debe ser `mainTemperature`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mainTemperature"
    ...
    ...
    />
```

si no tienes un `TextView` con el id o el id es diferente, esto es la causa por la cual `mainTemperature` tenga un valor null.

Comment: Mi TextView tiene ese id. Ese no es el problema. De hecho, si yo seteo un string cualquiera a esa view en el onCreate del Activity, se muestra el texto. El problema está en que mi text view "se vuelve null" en algún punto del proceso de request.

Comment: @AndrésLauga tu cargas el activity_main.xml del layout a travez  de  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) , tienes algún lugar en tu aplicación donde se vuelva a cambiar este layout?

Comment: No... activity_main.xml es mi único layout